# Issue with VBA script running between .xlsm and .xlsb formats

Tags: excel, vba

**Problem:**

Because the `.xlsb` (herein referred to  as `TheirFile.xlsb`) is downloaded from a third party twice a week, the VBA script must be held by the `.xlsm` (`MyFile.xlsm`).
The process is simple:
Focus `TheirFile.xlsb`
Apply some filters on the data (headers at row 3)
Select the cell `AW2` and copy the value (it contains a formula, this may be where the issue occurs)
Focus `MyFile.xlsm`
Select the cell `J28` and paste with `...pastespecial xlPasteAll`

However upon checking the code and hitting run, I get nothing in the cell.

**Attempts:**

Most of them are almost identical, and with the way I (attempt to) bug fix I honestly don't recall all of them.

I used variations on

```
Workbooks("TheirFile.xlsb").Activate
Range("AW2").Copy
```

to copy it without error, and

```
Workbooks("MyFile.xlsm").Activate
Range("j28").Select
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

to paste. Something here is failing without returning an error.

I have tried several ways of copying, even a clunky

```
Range("AW2").Select
x = Selection.Value
Workbooks("MyFile.xlsm").Activate
Range("j28").Select
Selection.Value = x
```

Which of course didn't work.

**Current code and additional info:**

Currently I have this in place

```
Option Explicit
Sub MyMacro() 'indentations for readability
Workbooks("TheirFile.xlsb").Activate
    If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    End If
    'various filters
    Dim x As Integer
    Workbooks("TheirFile.xlsb").Activate
    Range("AW2").Copy
    Workbooks("MyFile.xlsm").Activate
    Range("j28").Select
    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
End Sub
```

The cell `AW2` has a `=SUBTOTAL(9,cell:cell)` formula in it.
The cell `j28` is a merged cell.

**Questions:**

Is there a quick fix for my code?
Would it be more effective to simply perform the subtotal again inside of VBA to avoid the issue?

Answer (score 0):

**FIXED**

```
sheets("sheet1").range("AW2").copy
workbooks("MyFile.xlsm").activate
Range("j28").select
activecell.pastespecial xlPasteValues
```

`range("").select` appears not to work if the range is in a binary workbook but the macro is in a macro-enabled workbook.

Answer (score 0):

You can/should avoid any uneccessary select/active (also copy/paste is not needed to just transfer values)

```
Option Explicit

Sub MyMacro() 

    Dim wsSrc as worksheet

    Set wsSrc = workbooks("TheirFile.xlsb").worksheets(1) 'or ws name etc
    
    If wsSrc.FilterMode Then
        wsSrc.ShowAllData
    End If

    'various filters 'USE wsSrc not activesheet
   
    'ThisWorkbook is the wb where your code is running...
    ThisWorkbook.worksheets("sheetNameHere").range("J28").value = _
          wsSrc.range("AW2").value

End Sub
```